# Broadcast Receiver not starting Activity in Another app

Tags: java, android

I have two apps. One defines a broadcast receiver and the other send the broadcast.

This is the onReceive() method in the receiver --

```
@Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        String action = intent.getAction();
        Log.i("Started",action);
        Intent i = null;
        if(action.equals("LAUNCH_ATTRACTIONS_ACTIVITY")) {
            i = new Intent(context.getApplicationContext(), MainActivity.class);
        } else if(action.equals("LAUNCH_HOTELS_ACTIVITY")){
            i = new Intent(context.getApplicationContext(), HotelsActivity.class);
        }
        context.startActivity(i);
    }
```

"LAUNCH_ATTRACTIONS_ACTIVITY" and "LAUNCH_HOTELS_ACTIVITY" are two intent actions I have specified in the intent filter while registering the receiver in the MainActivity.class file like so -

```
intentFilter.addAction("LAUNCH_ATTRACTIONS_ACTIVITY");
intentFilter.addAction("LAUNCH_HOTELS_ACTIVITY");

registerReceiver(myReceiver, intentFilter, "edu.uic.cs478.fall22.mp3", null,RECEIVER_EXPORTED);
```

In the broadcast sender I am sending the broadcast like so -

```
sendBroadcast(new Intent("LAUNCH_ATTRACTIONS_ACTIVITY"));
```

Now, I first open the receiver application on the emulator and then I open the sender application and press a button to send the broadcast. But, the activity in the receiver only opens if the receiver app is the last opened app on the device before the sender app. So for example, if I open the receiver app and then navigate to the home screen, then open the sender app and send the broadcast, the activity is not opened even though broadcast is being received (Log.i() is run in the onReceive()). But, if I open the receiver app, then go to the recents menu and open the sender app and then send the broadcast, the receiver app responds and the activity is opened. Why is this happening and how do I fix this?

Edit: This is my Manifest.xml file for the receiver app.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    package="com.example.p3_app2">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:dataExtractionRules="@xml/data_extraction_rules"
        android:fullBackupContent="@xml/backup_rules"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.P3_App2"
        tools:targetApi="31">
        <receiver
            android:name=".MyReceiver"
            android:enabled="true"
            android:exported="true"></receiver>

        <activity
            android:name=".HotelsActivity"
            android:exported="false" />
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:exported="true">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Comment: Why is there even a broadcast receiver here?  If all you want to do is launch an Activity in another app, just set it to be exported=true and launch it via an Intent from the other app.

Comment: @aux can you share your `AndroidManifest.xml` ?

Comment: @GabeSechan uni project requirement.